# Проблемы при добавлении записи в базу с компонентом UniDAC

Tags: delphi, mysql

Пытаюсь добавить запись в базу MySQL через UniQuery, использую параметры. В итоге получаю такого рода ошибку:

Incorrect string VALUE: 'xC8xEBxFCxFFD...' FOR COLUMN 'path' at ROW 1

В столбец path записываю путь до файла нажестком диске мозможно есть некоторые запрешеные символы в MySQL ?

если что вот сам код добавления:

```
UniQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO files (name, path, comment, role) VALUES (:name, :path, :comment, :role)';
UniQuery1.ParamByName('path').Value := RzButtonEdit1.Text;
UniQuery1.ParamByName('name').Value := LabeledEdit1.Text;
UniQuery1.ParamByName('comment').Value := LabeledEdit2.Text;
if RzComboBox1.ItemIndex = 1 then UniQuery1.ParamByName('role').Value := 1 else
if RzComboBox1.ItemIndex = 0 then UniQuery1.ParamByName('role').Value := 10;
UniQuery1.Execute;
```

Comment: незнаю, сработает ли, попробуй через 
UniQuery1.ParamByName('path').Value := QuotedStr(RzButtonEdit1.Text);

Answer (score 1):

Сам разобрался, переделал базу в UTF8 все нормально стало. Как странно думал Delphi плохо работает с уникодом.